# Extending the "feet" of wire shelves for uneven surfaces

Tags: garage, shelving

I'm installing a number of wire shelves in a garage, but the feet don't adjust far enough to compensate for the slope.  Aside from bricks or other shims, what are my options for leveling these shelves?

In my case these are split sleeve wire shelves from InterMetro.  The factory feet are 3/8" 16 pitch UNC coarse with very little adjustment room:

[image: InterMetro Shelf Foot]

Comment: I don't get it -- why did you post a question and less than a minute later post the solution (with pictures)? Is your solution a viable solution or are you looking for a different solution?

Comment: @Johnny - http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: If someone has a better solution than mine, they are welcome to contribute it.  The more the merrier.  I happen to think my solution rocks, but the crowd is welcome to vote up whatever it likes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Metro does not seem to sell an appropriate foot leveler.

But a common carriage bolt will fit just fine.  The rounded head compensates for the slope far better than the flat factory foot, and you can file the raised numbers off easily:

[image: Easy InterMetro Shelf Foot Extension]

Or find a 3/8" 16 pitch "Combination Leg Equalizer" such as the Rockler #24315, which will spread the load more evenly:

[image: Leg Equalizer]

Comment: The carriage bolt is good also because it has the small square portion that you could use with a wrench of the bolt needs adjustment when there is a very heavy load on the shelves.

Comment: In fact I needed to make just such an adjustment to my carriage bolt to get an earthquake brace in.